# Google colab pro load large datasets is slow

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, google-colaboratory

Hello i have a problem to load the image datasets for my educational purposes.
I have done to load every single image path to pandas frame but i want to load the pixel of that image too. This is my code :

```
#data['image'] = data['path'].map(lambda x: np.asarray(Image.open(x).resize((224,224))))
data['image'] = data['path'].map(lambda x: np.asarray(Image.open(x)))
data.head()
```

This is the data in pandas dataframe

```
image_file              result  path
Normal/Normal-9093.png  Normal  drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Covid-19/Dataset...
Normal/Normal-908.png   Normal  drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Covid-19/Dataset...
Normal/Normal-9079.png  Normal  drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Covid-19/Dataset...
Normal/Normal-9109.png  Normal  drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Covid-19/Dataset...
Normal/Normal-9095.png  Normal  drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Covid-19/Dataset...
```

But in colab pro i'm still waiting for this running cell for 30 minutes++. I have done to enable GPU and High RAM but still same problem.
I try using Kaggle Notebooks using original datasets and it loads very fast, but in colab is very slow. Can i load the datasets with another technique pls? Thank you

Comment: How many images are there?

Comment: 21165 images @Dr.Snoopy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be fast load datasets you should load from kaggle not in drive folder

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).